# ng-show do not change when i fire function

Tags: angularjs

Can someone explain why spinerChange() function do not work properly?   http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/9907/

```
<div ng-controller="naujienosControler">
<button type="button" ng-click="spinerButtonChange()">Click Me!</button>
<div class="spinner" ng-show="spiner" >
    <div class="cube1"></div>
    <div class="cube2"></div>
</div>
</div>


var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('naujienosControler', function ($scope) {

var status = true;
$scope.spiner = status;
$scope.spinerButtonChange = function(){$scope.spiner = !$scope.spiner;};    
function spinerChange(){

setTimeout(function(){ alert("Why spiner dont disapear?????????"); $scope.spiner = false;},      3000);
console.log($scope.spiner);

};

spinerChange();
});
```

Comment: Check this as well "https://coderwall.com/p/udpmtq/angularjs-use-timeout-not-settimeout"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject and use [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) since you want angular to perform a `digest` after you do you action.

```
myApp.controller('naujienosControler', function ($scope, $timeout){   
    $timeout(function(){ $scope.spiner = false; }, 3000});
}
```

Edit (Thanks lechariotdor) : It's always a good practice to use "the angularjs world" wrappers since they run the `$apply` method that performs a `digest` on your scope and "syncs" the model with the change that occured.

Comment: I would add that it's an Angular best practice to use Angular 'wrappers' when they are existing ($timeout, $window, $document, ...) so strange things like that would be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

because javascript `setTimeout` is a event which is not trigger in angularjs scope, so angular doesn't know about changes outside the scope.

there is a way to achieve is use `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout` as below, here is the [DOC for $timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.spiner = !$scope.spiner;
}, 3000)
```

and don't forget to inject `$timeout` in to the controller as,

```
myApp.controller('naujienosControler', function ($scope, $timeout) {....
```

here is [the update](http://jsfiddle.net/gefcbmn0/)

---

there is another alternative using `$scope.$appy()` [here is a good tutorial about $apply()](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)

```
function spinerChange(){    
    setTimeout(function(){
        $scope.spiner = !$scope.spiner;
        $scope.$apply();    
    }, 3000);
    };    
    spinerChange();
});
```

**OR**

```
function spinerChange(){    
    setTimeout(function(){        
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.spiner = !$scope.spiner;
        });    
    }, 3000);
    };    
    spinerChange();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :-

```
$timeout(function(){ alert("Why spiner dont disapear?????????"); $scope.spiner = false;}, 500);
```